# PowerShell Regex with csv file

Tags: regex, powershell-4.0

I'm currently trying to match a pattern of IDs and replace with 0 or 1.

```
example pc0045601234 replace with 1234 the last 4 and add the 3rd digit in front "01234"
```

I tried the code below but the out only filled the userid column with No matching employee

```
$reportPath = '.\report.csv'`$reportPath = '.\report.csv'`
$csvPath = '.\output.csv'
$data = Import-Csv -Path $reportPath
$output = @()

foreach ($row in $data) {
    
    $table = "" | Select ID,FirstName,LastName,userid
    $table.ID = $row.ID
    $table.FirstName = $row.FirstName
    $table.LastName = $row.LastName
   

    switch -Wildcard ($row.ID)
    {
    {$row.ID -match 'P\d\d\d\d\d\D\D\D'} {$table.userid = "Contractor"; continue}
    {$row.ID -match 'SEC\d\d\d\D\D\D\D'} {$table.userid = "Contractor"; continue}
    {$row.ID.StartsWith("P005700477")} {$table.userid = $row.ID -replace "P005700477","0477"; continue}
    {$row.ID.StartsWith("P00570")} {$table.userid = $row.ID -replace "P00570","0"; continue}
    
   


    default {$table.userid = "No Matching Employee"}
    }
    
    $output += $table
    
}

$output | Export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $csvPath
```

Comment: So you start with pc0045601234 and want to end up with what?

Comment: I want to end up with 5 numbers. Whatever the 3rd number is be either 0 or 1 and the last 4 numbers. example PC05601234 be 01234 or PC15601234 be 11234

Answer (score 0):

Here are three different ways to achieve the desired result. The first two use the same technique, just written in a different way.

First we put the sample data in a variable as a multiline string array. This is the equivalent as `$text = Get-Content $somefile`

```
$text = @'
PC05601234
PC15601234
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine
```

Option 1 # convert to character array, select the 3rd and last 4 digits.

```
$text | foreach {-join ($_.ToChararray()| select -Skip 2 -First 1 -Last 4)}
```

Option 2 # same as above, requiring an extra `-join` to avoid spaces.

```
$text | foreach {(-join $_.ToChararray()| foreach{$_[2]+(-join $_[-4..-1])})}
```

Option 3 # my preference, regex. Capture the desired digits and replace the entire string with those two captured values.

```
$text -replace '^\D+(?!=\d)(\d)\w+([\d]{4}$)','$1$2'
```

All of these output

```
01234
11234
```

Further testing with different char/digit combinations and lengths.

```
$text = @'
PC05601234
PC15601234
PC0ABC124321
PC1DE4321
PC0A5678
PC1ABCD215678
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine
```

Running the new sample data through each option all produce this output

```
01234
11234
04321
14321
05678
15678
```

Comment: I'm little confused where are you adding this to current code to get the results.

Comment: What do you mean? The sample data is stored in variable $text and each option runs against $text